# Como fazer um sistema de pesquisa com Urls Amigaveis

Tags: php, url-amigável

Olá, eu gostaria de fazer um sistema de pesquisa com Urls amigáveis, pesquisei bastante e tentei muitas coisas, não ainda não consegui.

Gostaria que a url ficasse desta form `site.com/home/categoria/pesquisa`.

home.php

```
<form method="POST" class="floatLeft formSearch" action="home/go">
    <div class="formSearchDiv">
        <input type="text" name="searchInput" class="searchInput floatLeft">
        <select name="categorySearch" maxlength="255" class="categorySearch floatLeft">
                <option value="Todos" selected="selected">Todos</option>
                <option value="Serie">Serie</option>
                <option value="Filme">Filme</option>
                <option value="Anime">Anime</option>
                <option value="Filme Adulto">Filme Adulto</option>
                <option value="Desenho">Desenho</option>
                <option value="Software">Software</option>
                <option value="Jogos">Jogos</option>
        </select>
        <input type="image" name="submitSearch" src="<?=DIR_IMAGES ?>lupa.png" class="submitSearch floatLeft">
    </div>
</form>
require DIR_FUNCS.'/funcSQL.php';
$sql = new SQL();

if(isset($_POST['submitSearch']))
{   
    if(isset($_GET['go']))
    {
        if(preg_match("^/[A-Za-z]+/", $_POST['searchInput']))
        {
            $search = $_POST['searchInput']; 
            echo $search;
            $sql->listTorrentSearch($search, "Todos");
        }
    }
}
```

FuncSQL.php

```
public function listTorrentSearch($search, $category) 
{
    $conn = $this->openSQL();
    $cont = 0;

    if($category == "Todos")
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM torrents WHERE Nome LIKE '".$search."%'");
    }
    else
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM torrents WHERE Nome LIKE '".$search."%' AND Categoria='".$category."'");
    }

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

        if($cont < 25)
        {
        $name = $row['Nome'];
        $category = $row['Categoria'];
        $size = $row['Size'];
        $magnet = $row['Magnet'];

        $createTorrentClass = new CreateTorrent();

        $createTorrentClass->createTorrentDiv($name, $category, $size, $magnet);

        $cont++;
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

.htacess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

tratarUrl.php

```
$pUrl = strip_tags(trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url', FILTER_DEFAULT)));
$sUrl = (empty($pUrl) ? "index" : $pUrl);
$url = array_filter(explode('/', $sUrl));

if (count($url) > 1) {
$cont = 1;
foreach ($url as $arg) {
    define("PARAM" . $cont, $arg);
    $cont++;
}
} else if (count($url) == 1) {
if (file_exists(DIR_PAGES . $url[0] . '.php')) {
    $pag = DIR_PAGES . $url[0] . '.php';
} else {
    if($url[0] != 'index')
    {
        $pag = DIR_PAGES . '404.php';
    }
    else
    {
        $pag = DIR_PAGES . 'home.php';
    }
}
} else {
$pag = DIR_PAGES . '404.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucas,

Nesse [blog](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis) tem uma explicação bem completa, mas resumindo você deverá fazer o seguinte:

Você precisa marcar os endereços atuais do seu site e como você quer que eles fiquem. Siga um padrão para manter as mesmas informações organizadas. Exemplos:

- http://meusite.com/produtos.php?id=8 (URL atual)
- http://meusite.com/produtos/tenis/8/ (Nova URL)

Vamos começar com o exemplo da página de contato que atualmente você acessa pelo endereço http://www.meusite.com.br/contato.php.

Vá até a raiz do seu site e edite ou crie um arquivo chamado .htaccess.
Coloque as seguintes linhas:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^contato/?$ /contato.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

O IfModule é como um bloco de condição que verifica se um certo módulo existe e está habilitado.

A regra é escrita pelo RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^contato/?$/contato.php [NC,L]
```

A validação da URL é feita via expressão regular, o circunflexo ^ significa “inicio”, o cifrão $ significa “fim” e a parte /? significa uma barra opcional, ou seja: A reescrita acontecerá para as URLs meusite.com.br/contato e meusite.com.br/contato/.

Na parte /contato.php informamos para o servidor qual arquivo atenderá pela requisição. Preste atenção que é nessa parte que dizemos ao servidor qual o formato da nossa antiga URL.

Na parte **`[NC,L]`** há  flags, o `NC` de *"no case"* (ignora a diferença entre maiúsculas e minúsculas) e **`L`** de *"last"* faz com que se essa regra for utilizada, nenhuma outra regra seja usada.

Se você quiser aprender mais sobre flags, recomendo a leitura da documentação do Apache.

Se quiser trabalahar com URLs mais complexas, que contenham valores variáveis como o exemplo meusite.com/produtos/tenis/ verifique aqui:

- http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis-com-regras-complexas

Comment: Olá, dei uma olhada no tutorial, quando eu uso a regra `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?s=3&c=5` e acesso `site.com/?s=3&c=2` ele retorna `3 e 5`, porem quando eu uso a regra `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?s=$1&c=$2` e acesso o mesmo site, ele retorna `index.php e vazio`.

Comment: @LucasCarezia você quer redirecionar site.com/?s=3&c=2 para o que? Para site.com/index/ ou site.com/3/2 ou outro destino?

Comment: RewriteRule ^index/([0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?s=$1&c=$2 [NC]

Comment: O exemplo acima deverá transformar sua URL em index/1/2/